# Removing a random page break in latex

Tags: latex, page-break

I am trying to write a CV but keep getting a page break between the center section and the \section*{Professional Experience}. If I remove the section* I still get a page break but just after the 'Professional Experience' wording. I have tried \nopagebreak and \filpage and neither have worked. Below is a code snippet:

````
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand \VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{absolutelynopagebreak}
  {\par\nobreak\vfil\penalty0\vfilneg
   \vtop\bgroup}
  {\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
   \prevdepth=\tpd}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{center} 
\textbf{\huge Joe M. M. Davies} \vspace{5mm}\\
j.m.m.davies@*******  $|$ [ADDRESS] \vspace{2.5mm} \\
07******* $|$ linkedin.com/in/j******* $|$ https://gitlab.cern.ch/j******** \vspace{2.5mm} \\
Strong analytical, communication and problem solving abilities, developed through my education and work experiences. Looking for a position in data science, suiting my expertise in machine learning.
\end{center} 

\section*{Professional Experience} 
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
July 2019 - September 2019&{\bf Data Science Intern, [REDACTED]}\\ [5pt]
&{Receipt Bank is an accounting/bookkeeping firm that uses machine learning to extract information from receipts. I was working to segment their user base using exploratory data analysis and, specifically, unsupervised machine learning techniques such as k-means clustering. This involved using python with packages like: sklearn, numpy, pandas and scipy. Also developed skills in SQL using both Looker and the SQLalchemy library in python. The results were insights that I presented to the business which aided them in understanding how their users interact with the service (via web or mobile apps). For this I was awarded a monthly salary of £1800 per month. \vspace{5mm}}\\```

(Bits and pieces removed to preserve anonymity)
Many thanks!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your pagebreak could be that right after `\section*{Professional Experience}` you start a table which might need an entire page (so the "Professional Experience" does not fit), but there seems to be code missing, so I cannot tell.

regards,
Lisa

Comment: Thank you, this was it. I enclosed the tabular section with \begin{figure} and \end{figure} and that worked.